# How do i express Try/Catch in a control flow graph?

Tags: c#, cyclomatic-complexity, control-flow-graph

I'm trying to calculate some **Cyclomatic Complexity**, hence trying to draw a Control Flow Graph. Firstly i'm trying to make it for a fairly simple method.

Firstly i tried drawing it for just the try part like this: 
[image: Flow Graph]

**Heres the method:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GraphMethod([FromForm]string str)
    {
        try
        {
            int affectedRows = this._copyManager.CreateCopy(str);
            if (affectedRows < 1) return BadRequest("Error!");

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

How would i extend it to include the entire method, and the try part?

This is my first ever **Control Flow Graph**, so if i messed it up i would also like to know.

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be used to control flow (as described [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/326382)) and therefore (at least in my logic) not be represented in a control flow graph

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)` is such a bad anti-pattern.

Comment: @MindSwipe thank you, i will remove my try/catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `TryCreateCopy` method and do something very similar to @saya imad's answer
Something like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GraphMethod([FromForm]string str)
{ 
    // These two if statements can be concatenated into one, 
    // but that would be a bit hard to read
    if (this._copyManager.TryCreateCopy(str, out var affectedRows))
        if (affectedRows > 1)
            return Ok();

    return BadRequest("Error!");
}

// _copyManager Method, there's probably a better way for you
public bool TryCreateCopy(string str, out int affectedRows)
{
    try
    {
        affectedRows = CreateCopy(str);
    }
    // Please also don't do `catch (Exception)`, 
    // if you know which exception gets thrown always catch that
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        affectedRows = -1;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Where the TryCreateCopy method returns true when a copy was created without an exception being thrown, false if one has been thrown* and an out variable with the number of affected rows

---

* There is probably a better way of doing this than what I showed you (e.g validate method?) as try/ catch is quite resource intensive

Answer (score 1):

For my part i recommande you to use this code , more is simple , more is efficient

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GraphMethod([FromForm]string str)
{       
        if (this._copyManager.CreateCopy(str) < 1) 
            return BadRequest("Error!");

        return Ok();      
}
```

Comment: I agree in removing the try and catch, but i will keep the "affectedRows" variable. I know that your suggestion gives me the same result, with less code, but i like the readability in naming what i'm comparing.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: One problem: What if an exception gets thrown? OPs question indicates that `CreateCopy` can throw an exception